# Planetary and Lunar Landing: Documents & other References

Tags: discussion, resources

I suppose it is appropriate to put this category of questions on meta. 
This is too broad but I am looking for resources and references for Lunar/Planetary landers/landing.

Looked up NTRS using a few keywords. 
However, I would like to get recommendations from SE community. Some must read docs/books,especially for landing sequence, procedures, Guidance, Navigation and Control, and other resources, if any.

Comment: Kuldeep, please check our meta repository: [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/249/resources-and-references-on-the-topic-of-space-exploration). **Everyone else**: Please post your replies to Kuldeep there as well as here.

Comment: I am familiar with the question. However, there were almost no references or resources related to this question. So, I thought I'd post it as a new question. Looking forward to answers similar to the reference repository.